# Onchange field not working OpenERP

Tags: python, xml, treeview, odoo

I'm trying to show a `res.partner` field, which is called `phone` into the treeview of a sale.order.

But it is not showing anything, just the name of the field without data. This is my code on `sale.order`

```
phone : fields.char('Telefono del Cliente'),
```

Onchange function for this field:

```
def onchange_phone(self, cr, uid, ids, phone, context=None):
res = {}
    if phone:
        obj = self.pool.get('res.partner')
        browse(cr, uid, phone)
        res['phone'] = obj.phone
    return {'value' : res}
```

On `res.partner` the field is also called `phone` which is obviously the client's phone, i need to show it on the `sale.order` treeview, this is the code on my `sale_view.xml`:

```
<field name="phone" on_change="onchange_phone(phone)"/>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion, If you want phone number of partner, than you should not create on_change of phone field. You can get phone number in 2 ways.

First way and best way, In sale.order, `onchange_partner_id()` method is their, you need to override that method and update vals with phone number of partner.

And Second way and long way, You may override `create()` method and `write()` method of sale.order.

create() method trick:

- in create() method, you can take partner id from the context. For example `vals.get('partner_id')`

write() method trick:

- in write() method, you have id of created record so you need to simply browse that record and write phone number of partner.

Answer (score 1):

As Odedra suggested, you should do this like so (this is taken from sale.py file):

```
def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part, context=None):
    if not part:
        return {'value': {'partner_invoice_id': False, 'partner_shipping_id': False,  'payment_term': False, 'fiscal_position': False}}

    part = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, part, context=context)
    addr = self.pool.get('res.partner').address_get(cr, uid, [part.id], ['delivery', 'invoice', 'contact'])
    pricelist = part.property_product_pricelist and part.property_product_pricelist.id or False
    payment_term = part.property_payment_term and part.property_payment_term.id or False
    fiscal_position = part.property_account_position and part.property_account_position.id or False
    dedicated_salesman = part.user_id and part.user_id.id or uid
    phone = part.phone or False
    val = {
        'partner_invoice_id': addr['invoice'],
        'partner_shipping_id': addr['delivery'],
        'payment_term': payment_term,
        'fiscal_position': fiscal_position,
        'user_id': dedicated_salesman,
        'phone': phone,
    }
    if pricelist:
        val['pricelist_id'] = pricelist
    return {'value': val}
```

Note that you should not do that on base module, but instead create your own module and inherit it to sale.order model. What is more, onchange will not work on tree view (like you suggested), but you can easily show it on the tree - you have to first put it on your form with the onchange provided, then modify tree view to show phone number.

Comment: As per your note, you have specified to inherit.So in the onchange function also please specify to call super() so that we are not changing the onchange_partner_id function